# Python Kivy: How to access button states in loop and change transition in python

Tags: python, button, kivy, ids

How would I access button states in a for loop. I want to check which button has been pressed and then based on this select the screen I want to be displayed. I know I can access the state through ids.state, however I don't know how to do this in a loop. The below code is how I access I am accessing at the moment.

```
if self.root.ids.main_screen.ids.second_screen_button.state == "down":
        self.sm.current = "second_screen"
```

Is it possible to check every buttons state and then return id of whichever button is pressed? Or to access the id of the button pressed? I can then compare this against the screen ids.

Additionally, how do I change transition when button is not with screen root. The below code doesn't work. It gives the following error AttributeError: 'BackgroundLayout' object has no attribute 'manager'. Which makes sense as the root is a RelativeLayout.

```html
<BackgroundLayout>:
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        text: "Home button"
        size: root.width/4, root.height/4
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right", duration=0.25)
            app.home_screen()
```

Should the transition be changed in python in this case? I haven't been able to find how to do this dynamically in python.

Please see below code for reference. Please note that I removed the transition from below code so that it would run

<main.py>

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def change_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = "steak_screen"


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BackgroundLayout(RelativeLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = Manager()
        return self.sm

    # Change screen based on button pressed

    def change_screen(self):
        if self.root.ids.main_screen.ids.second_screen_button.state == "down":
            self.sm.current = "second_screen"

        if self.root.ids.main_screen.ids.third_screen_button.state == "down":
            self.sm.current = "third_screen"

    # Return to main screen when pressed
    def home_screen(self):
        self.sm.current = "main_screen"


MainApp().run()
```

<main.kv>

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

#Background layout for every screen
<BackgroundLayout>:
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        text: "Home button"
        size: root.width/4, root.height/4
        on_release:
            app.home_screen()


# Main Screen
<MainScreen>
    BackgroundLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Home"
        Button:
            id: second_screen_button
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width/4, root.height/4
            pos: root.x + root.width/4, 0
            text: "second screen button"
            on_press:
                self.state = "down"
                app.change_screen()
                self.state = "normal"
        Button:
            id: third_screen_button
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width/4, root.height/4
            pos: root.x + root.width/2, 0
            text: "third screen button"
            on_press:
                self.state = "down"
                app.change_screen()
                self.state = "normal"

<SecondScreen>
    BackgroundLayout:

<ThirdScreen>
    BackgroundLayout:

# Screen manager
<Manager>:
    id: _manager

    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
        manager: _manager
        name: "main_screen"

    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen
        manager: _manager
        name: "second_screen"

    ThirdScreen:
        id: third_screen
        manager: _manager
        name: "third_screen"
```

Comment: Try to produce a minimal reproductible example, you have posted too much code. Remember that people have to read and understand your post in order to help you

Comment: I have removed parts of the code now that aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I have now update my question with new code. I think thats as small as I can make it to showcase what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1.Question 1
How would I access button states in a for loop. I want to check which button has been pressed and then based on this select the screen I want to be displayed. I know I can access the state through ids.state, however I don't know how to do this in a loop. 
Is it possible to check every buttons state and then return id of whichever button is pressed? Or to access the id of the button pressed? I can then compare this against the screen ids.

- Answer:
  You are making the Buttons behave like ToggleButtons, yet they are Buttons.
  So Unless you exclusively do not want to use ToggleButton class, loop through with the inbuilt function isinstance(object,Class) ;
  According to your kv file, the buttons are children of the BackgroundLayout in the MainScreen root Widget. So this function will look for the btns in the BackgroundLayout, and return the id of the pressed button.

```py
def get_id_of_pressed_btn(self):
    for child_1 in self.children:
        # in this case child_1 = BackgroundLayout
        for child_2 in child_1:
            # checks if child_2 is a Button object 
            if isinstance(child_2, Button):
                if child_2.state = 'down':
                    return child_2.id
```

This will work only if there is always one Button in the down state, which again is the reason behind ToggleButtons. If you still insist on using Buttons replace the:
 *return child_2.id*  with a list variable that shall collect the ids of all buttons with 'down' state.

But then again, I repeat unless you don't like the ToggleButton class, I advise that you use it. Because you could jus change screens by directly setting the ScreenManager.current property to which ever screen you want along with the transition right within the Button block in kv, like so;

```
Button:
    size_hint: None, None
    text: "Home button"
    size: root.width/4, root.height/4
    on_release:
        root.manager.current = 'main_screen'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have changed the buttons to Toggle Buttons and changed the code to child_1.children as it gave an error background layout is not iterable. However, it still comes up with the error AttributeError: 'ToggleButton' object has no attribute 'id'

Also in regards to the transitions how do I set the transition for the home button as root.manager doesn't work. Currently I have got around this by resetting the transitions after every button is pressed, which is not an ideal solution. I would rather it is set when home button is pressed.